# matlab expression entered as text string

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am creating a GUI in MATLAB where the user should be able to type in (enter a string) an expression which manipulates 6 variables which have been derived from the GUI.

For example, the variables are:

```
 t1,t2,t3,t4,t5 and t6
```

which are floating point numbers. The user should be able to type in an expression containing many mathematical operands and refer to the variables named.

For example:

```
(((t1*t2)/(t3*t4))+sqrt(t5-t6)))
```

but it could be any mathematical expression.

I have had a look at the eval series of functions, but I am not sure it is applicable. I thought I would ask for some help and guidance.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not think that the `eval` function is applicable?

Comment: Define your variables, define `string = '(((t1*t2)/(t3*t4))+sqrt(t5-t6))'` (as the user would) and do `eval(string)`. You'll see it _is_ applicable, and it probably does what you want. BTW, the last closing parenthesis should be removed

Comment: Thank you for quick replies. I obviously may have misunderstood the eval function. From looking at the MATLAB example, it was not apparent to me, but this level of MATLAB programming is new to me, so I will try your suggestions tomorrow morning. Thanks once again. I will report back.